# How to set the working directory of a command in a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, working-directory

Let's say I have these commands:

```
Prog1.exe
D:\SomeDir\Prog2.exe
Prog3.exe
```

Now, say for the second line, I would like the working directory to be D:\SomeDir, but in Prog1.exe and Prog3.exe I want the default working directory (normally, where my .bat file is). If I try this

```
Prog1.exe
cd D:\SomeDir
D:\SomeDir\Prog2.exe
Prog3.exe
```

Apparently Prog3 will be executed in SomeDir, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You could use the pushd/popd commands (help with `pushd /?`)

```
Prog1.exe
Pushd D:\SomeDir
Prog2.exe
popd
Prog3.exe
```

Answer (score 13):

You could use the cd command (help with `cd /?`) with the `%~dp0`, batch file path, variable.

```
Prog1.exe
cd D:\SomeDir
Prog2.exe
cd %~dp0
Prog3.exe
```

For a complete list of `%~` modifiers see `call /?` or `for /?` help.

However, I only add this as to provide a more complete answer on Stack Overflow. I would RECOMMEND using jeb's solution above.

Answer (score 13):

What worked for me is adding a `/d`:

```
cd /d C:\nginx
ECHO Stopping nginx...
start nginx -s quit
```

(When I didn't have the `/d`, it didn't work.)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18310141/470749 tries to explain it.

Comment: what does /d mean?

Comment: @СеменихинМаксим, From the documentation: "Use the /D switch to change current drive in addition to changing current directory for a drive." Basically, you always want to specify it when changing dir to arbitrary absolute paths.