# What does it mean by command cd /d %~dp0 in Windows

Tags: windows, cmd

Can someone please help me to understand the command `cd /d %~dp0` and its purposes. Again dos command is below

```
cd /d %~dp0
```

Please help me to get the meaning of it.

Answer (score 148):

Let's dissect it. There are three parts:

1. `cd` -- This is change directory command.
2. `/d` -- This switch makes `cd` change both drive and directory at once. Without it you would have to do `cd %~d0 & cd %~p0`. (`%~d0` Changs active drive, `cd %~p0` change the directory).
3. `%~dp0` -- This can be dissected further into three parts:

   1. `%0` -- This represents zeroth parameter of your batch script. It expands into the name of the batch file itself.
   2. `%~0` -- The `~` there strips double quotes (`"`) around the expanded argument.
   3. `%dp0` -- The `d` and `p` there are modifiers of the expansion. The `d` forces addition of a drive letter and the `p` adds full path.

Comment: In other words, it changes the current directory to the batch file's location.

Answer (score 41):

`~dp0` : d=drive, p=path, %0=full path\name of this batch-file.

`cd /d %~dp0` will change the path to the same, where the batch file resides.

See `for /?` or `call /?` for more details about the `%~...` modifiers.
See `cd /?` about the `/d` switch.