# To change drive and directory at the same time

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

Hi presently I am using command prompt frequently. Every time I need to access different folders of different drives so **I need to change drive and directory at the same time** For this I got a solution:
**C:> CD /D D:\JAVA** it's working fine. But why we are using "/D"

So please explain me why we are using /D.

Comment: /D implies switching both drive and folder simultaneously. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309941/what-does-it-mean-by-command-cd-d-dp0-in-windows) covers the subject further. In addition, try google next time. You could have found the answer to this question in five minutes max. I'm not being critical but offering some professional advice. :)

Comment: Thank you CalebB I'll try google next time.....Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CD /D ...` changes the current *drive* in addition to changing folder.

---

Source [CD Change Directory - Select a Folder (and drive)](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
>   CD [/D] [drive:][path]
>   CD [..]
> ```
>
> **Key**
>
> `/D` : change the current DRIVE in addition to changing folder.

...

> **Changing the Current drive**
>
> Enter the drive letter followed by a colon.
>
> ```
> C:> E:
> E:>
> ```
>
> **To change drive and directory at the same time, use CD with the /D
>   switch**.
>
> ```
> C:> cd /D 
> E:\utils E:\utils\>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`cd /?` Will answer that for you.

The alternative to `cd /d d:\java` is `d:` then `cd java`. If you then changed to another drive (say `C:`) and ran `dir d:` you would still see the contents of the java directory. i.e. The OS remembers what directory each drive is currently looking at. Likewise you can just run C:>`cd d:\otherDir` c:>`dir d:` and see the contents of otherDir.

Answer (score 0):

By using the command -

```
CD [/D] [drive:][path]
```

on cmd **it means to jump to a different directory** where `/D` simply means to jump to another directory. This command **also gives freedom in using different drives** unlike the `cd [drive:][path]` command.
By using the above command it is also possible to move to the same previous working directory in a specific Drive just by writing Drive name followed by a colon. For eg:

```
C:\Users>cd /D G:\FUN

G:\FUN>C:

C:\Users>
```